# Different tick sizes on the Y axis of a D3js line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I haven't found any examples of this so far, but I was hoping the readers at Stack have run into this situation before.

We have a Y axis where the range from 0-200 isn't very interesting.  We'd like to "squish" this area of the y axis and have the gap become larger as the Y axis values grow so that the top end of the spectrum shows a lot more movement in the line graph.

This would mean that the ticks on the Y axis would grow as they went up in range and allow the graph to show larger differences near the top end of the spectrum.

I can see that Y doesnt take a function, but has anyone done something like this and if so does anyone have any working examples?

If its not possible with D3 has anyone done something similar with highcharts?

Comment: Have you thought about use a log scale axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE**

Please make sure that the ideas in the graph are still clear if you use such a scale. Be aware that the lines are only built based on start and end point and are not "kinked" when traversing the break in the axis.
When writing the answer I wasn't aware that you have a line graph and values below 200.

**ANSWER**

Assuming that you want to use a linear scale, you could e.g. try the following:

```
newScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,200,1000]).range([0,100,1000])
```

An axis could e.g. look like this:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(newScale)
  .orient('bottom');
d3.select("#someSVG").append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + 123 + ')')
  .call(xAxis);
```

Consequently, you'd get:

[image]

Looking at your codepen, you might want to try:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height,height * 9 / 10, 0]);
```

and then use as domain:

```
y.domain([0, 200, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.close;
    })]);
```

so in this example, you allocate 1/10th of the height to the first 200.

[image]

Comment: I believe so, I'm working off this codepen http://codepen.io/ryansmc/pen/Gdigb where the Y axis on the left would need to be squished.  I tried plugging in your code but it kill the entire Y axis

Comment: I should note that the numbers on the Y axis are also fixed and never change.  its basically always 0 - 850.  The X axis is simply set up for 12 months of the year.

Comment: @Mr.BigglesWorth: see update answer, I hope that helps!